# (Select query) como deixar mais dinâmico?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte método select na minha classe CRUD e utilizo ele em toda a aplicação, porem preciso deixar ele mais dinâmico, por exemplo preciso usar um ORDER BY, também utilizar outros campos diferente do $user_id, alguma dica?

```
//Select on database
public function select($where = null, $user_id, $fields = '*')
{
    if($where != null){
        $where = " WHERE ";
    }

    $query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM `{$this->table}` {$where} `user_id`=:user_id ORDER BY id DESC";
    $stmt   = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(":user_id", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Eu faço desta forma utilizando PDO:**

```
/** @var PDO */
private static $connect = null;

/**
 * Conecta com o banco de dados com o pattern singleton
 * Retorna um objeto PDO!
 */
private static function Conectar(){

    try {

        Setup::checkLocal();

        if(self::$connect == null) {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.Setup::$host.';dbname='.Setup::$base;
            $options = [ PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8" ];
            self::$connect = new PDO($dsn, Setup::$user, Setup::$pass, $options);
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'PDOException: erro ao conectar ao banco de dados.';
        //PHPErro($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
        die;
    }

    self::$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //self::$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);

    return self::$connect;
}

/** Retorna um objeto PDO Singleton Pattern */
public static function getConn(){
    return self::Conectar();
}

public static function prepareQuery($query, $params){

    $preparedQuery = self::getConn()->prepare($query);
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $preparedQuery->bindValue($key, $value);
    }

    $preparedQuery->execute();
    $result = $preparedQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    self::$connect = null;

    return $result;
}
```

E costumo acessar desta forma:

```
$qrSelect = "SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela WHERE campo1 = :campo1 ORDER BY campo1 ASC";

$params = [":campo1" => $valor];
$retorno = Conexao::prepareQuery($qrSelect, $params);
```

Eu sempre passo a query inteira. O que muda sempre são os parâmetros. Eu não vejo muito ganho em economizar as palavras `select` e `from` na hora de chamar o método `select`, se para compensar você terá q passar vários parâmetros e fazer outras validações.

Comment: É que uso o select em muitos lugarem no código, e queria poder tem um método bem completo e dinâmico que seja utilizado em toda a aplicação..

Comment: Eu acho q vc poderia passar apenas dois parâmetros no seu método select. uma string q seria a query e um array com os parâmetros. Depois vc trata dentro do método. Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim: https://jsfiddle.net/t57r04o2/

Comment: Hmm.. é mais ou menos isso que eu quero.. vc deu uma boa ideia, vou ver oque faço aqui.. vlws!

Comment: Blz! espero ter ajudado! ;)